# Flashing Libremesh on Router TP-Link Archer C20i

Tags: openwrt

I am trying to flash Libremesh on a `TP-Link Archer C20i` Router. The router already successfully runs OpenWRT version 21.02.0-rc3.
I keep running into the problem that I cannot copy the Libremesh image created by [Chef](https://chef.libremesh.org/?version=21.02.0-rc1&target=ramips%2Fmt7620&id=tplink_archer-c20i) on the router with scp, because after ~70% of the image (that is ~4MB) scp says `No space left on device`. Although the Flash size of the router is 8MB according to OpenWRT [documentation](https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/archer_c20i), and the image size is only 5,9MB according to `ls -lh`.

I tried using different versions of Libremesh: `21.02.0-rc3` and `21.02.0-rc1` both had this problem, last stable version `19.07` does not have this router model available.

I included the following packages in the `Customize` section of Chef:

```
base-files busybox ca-bundle -dnsmasq dnsmasq-dhcpv6 dropbear firewall fstools 
ip6tables iptables kmod-gpio-button-hotplug kmod-ipt-offload kmod-usb2 
libgcc libustream-wolfssl logd luci netifd odhcp6c odhcpd-ipv6only opkg ppp
ppp-mod-pppoe procd rssileds swconfig uboot-envtools ucert uci uclient-fetch
urandom-seed urngd wpad-mesh-wolfssl wpa-cli bmx7 bmx7-iwinfo bmx7-json bmx7-sms
bmx7-table bmx7-tun bmx7-uci-config bmx7-auto-gw-mode lime-proto-bmx7 
lime-proto-anygw uhttpd-mod-lua shared-state shared-state-dnsmasq_hosts 
shared-state-dnsmasq_leases wifi-unstuck-wa bmx7-dnsupdate kmod-mt76x0e kmod-rt2800-soc
```

Is it really the case that `TP-Link Archer C20i` is genuinely too small for Libremesh? Do I have to leave away packages? Any hint to make Libremesh work on this router is appreciated :)